# Unexpected output in pthread

Tags: c, posix

**Hello for above code in thread it is displaying 0 (tid = 0) instead of 8... what may be the reason ? In PrintHello function I am printing threadid but I am sending value 8 but it is printing 0 as output**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   int *tid;
   tid = threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%d!\n", *tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t thread1,thread2;
   int rc;
   int value = 8;
   int *t;
   t = &value;

   printf("In main: creating thread 1");
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
        }


   printf("In main: creating thread 2\n");
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
        }


   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual object that holds `8` is `value` which is local to your `main` function so accessing after `main` has exited is not valid.

You don't wait for your child threads to finish before they attempt to access this local variable so the behaviour is undefined.

One fix would be to make your `main` wait for it's child threads before exiting using `pthread_join`.

(I've assumed that you've made a typo in your second call to `pthread_create` and meant to pass `thread2` instead of `thread1`.)

E.g.

```
/* in main, before exiting */
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

Comment: Also, while passing the parameter shouldn't it be `&t`?

Comment: I mean the 4th parameter passed to `pthread_create`? I haven't used pthreads so was not that sure.

Comment: Oops..sorry..I got confused between `value` and `t`. Didn't see `t` being defined as `int*`.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Thank you for the fix :) I have not tested it yet once I go to workplace today I ll test it :).. Actually what I am trying to do is, thread1 is reading a value and that value is processed by thread2 and give the output.. So is there anyway to pass the value between threads ? can I use shared memory ? or declare a global variable in main() file ? Thank you

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Actually I have tested this code in beaglebone (ARM) , there it was giving 0 as output when I test the same code in my laptop with (x86) ubuntu 12.04 it is giving output as 8 itself. I didnt add the pthread_join also still it is giving 8 as output. Is there any reason ? may be version problem ?

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK: Behaviour that is undefined could cause anything to happen. I've pointed out the only error that I spotted in your code. You need to fix it one way or another even if you observe the correct results in one system some of the time.

Comment: @Charles Bailey. "Behaviour that is undefined could cause anything to happen" yes u are right. Thank you so much. :)