# multithreading, thread sync

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

[NOOBS QUESTION]
Good evening to everyone. First, sorry for my English, I'm trying to know better this language.

I've three files:

Main.cpp -> Contain the graphics interface, menu thread and audio thread.
Lettore.cpp -> Contain the functions to reconize the type of the file and use the correct library for play the audio, also contain the function for stop, play,pause,skip a song.
The two audio code library -> That decode the track and send it to ao for playing.

Now the question is: How I can implement this? My difficulty is in the main file. I write the "menu"("play/pause,skip,ecc....) thread code. Now the audio thread must be separated from the main(because can't block the program, the function for play is in a while), but must communicate with menu thread... How I can do this?

I'm using g++ with C++11 thread module.
Thank you for your time

Ps: if this question isn't congruent with the rules i modify this question instantly!

Comment: Post what you have done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a queue common to menu and audio thread. Menu thread fills the queue with commands and the audio thread occasionally checks it.

You can find one implementation of a lock-free thread safe queue in http://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++

Comment: Here is another: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pthread, use mutex variables or queues. There are lot of example available for pthread communication.
[pthread mutex variables to communicate among threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868678/communication-between-two-threads-in-pthread)

[inter thread communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872593/c-c-implementation-of-a-mailbox-for-inter-thread-communication)